# Every http get request from Angular generate new csfr token in laravel

Tags: angular, laravel

I am making small application in Angular 11 and Laravel.

For every http POST/DELETE/PUT/PATCH request I need to have Laravel's token.
I created small service to take current token from laravel.

In Angular it looks like this:

token.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {

  private url = 'http://token.loc/token';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
```

token.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { TokenService } from '../token.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-token',
  templateUrl: './token.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./token.component.css']
})
export class TokenComponent implements OnInit {

  token: string;

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  getToken() {
    this.tokenService.get().subscribe(data => this.token = data.token);
  }
}
```

token.component.html

```
<button (click)="getToken()">token</button>
{{ token }}
```

In Laravel I have:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class TokenController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function get()
    {
        return [
            'token' => csrf_token(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Problem is that on every click on frontend I get new token. I run this from http://localhost:4200

But when I run http://token.loc/token in browser for every request I get the same token
which is correct.

The same is when I use Postman or Insomnia for that.

Why ?

Comment: I don't see any logic in the front end or back end that would return the same token on every request. Why would you expect it in that case?

Comment: You really don’t have to do anything special in Angular to make csrf work.. if Angular finds the correct cookie, it will deal with setting the correct headers automagically: https://angular.io/guide/security#http